# UDP socket C#.NET

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, udp

I'm using udp socket in .NET;in particular I made a program that,by udp socket,sends image,from picture box,to other program.

This is the code:

this is the listener part where the socket receives image from port 8000

```
private void Listening()
        {
            IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 8000);

            Socket newsock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                            SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

            newsock.Bind(ipep);


            int recv;
            IPEndPoint sender1 = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.1"), 6000);

            EndPoint Remote = (EndPoint)sender1;
            byte[] data = new byte[11230];


            recv = newsock.ReceiveFrom(data,ref Remote);

            MemoryStream x = new MemoryStream(data);

            Image y = Image.FromStream(x);

            pictureBox2.Image = y;

         }
```

this is the sending part where socket sends image
[code]

```
private void Sending()
        {
            IPAddress host = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
            IPEndPoint hostep = new IPEndPoint(host, 8000);
            Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram,    ProtocolType.Udp);

            sock.Connect(hostep);


            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

            pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

            sock.Send(ms.ToArray());

          }
```

Both parts are in the same PC.

My problem is when it's called "Send" function in the "Sending" part it generates exception whit this message:

"The size of the message sent on a datagram socket is larger than the internal message buffer or some other network limit, or the size of the receive buffer of the datagram are lower than those of the datagram itself"

Thanks for your time

Comment: Don't use UDP. Seriously. Unless you **really** know you *need* UDP, do not use it.

Comment: The error message is quite clear: the amount of data you're trying to send is too large for UDP. Besides that, there are tons of problems in your code, so +1 to what @JonathonReinhart said.

Comment: @dtb except for the choice of UDP instead of TCP,what are the errors?

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you against your current approach. What you are attempting to achieve is not so simple to accomplish in a robust manner. I would advise you to check out the excellent zeromq library that nicely encapsulates raw socket api's and that provides a number of specific patterns to send and receive data.

For the problem that you are describing, the "publish / subscribe" pattern supported by zeromq might be a very good fit.

Zeromq is a crossplatform c library, but good CLR/.NET wrappers are available for it. I would urge you to read this article for example as an introduction: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/488207/ZeroMQ-via-Csharp-Introduction

Comment: https://github.com/zeromq/netmq A 100% native C# implementation of ZeroMQ for .NET

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty straitforward: you are exceeding the limit of message size. In UDP, you send datagrams, not a stream of bytes. In IPv4, you cannot send a UDP datagram larger than 65507 bytes (i.e., 64KiB including IPv4 and UDP headers).

UDP suits well for passing short messages, but for transferring large amounts of data TCP is more preferable.

Comment: Hi,this is a example, but in the reality I must send frames from webcam.How to make the part of sending? I won't use TCP because it's slow and not preferable for this scope

Comment: @alessiovinaccia Ohhh... this is a streaming webcam feed. See, that's incredibly information that you should have provided from the beginning. In that case, the answer is simple: **use [RTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol)**.

Comment: I have 3 questions foryou:                                                              1)from what I understood about UDP protocol doesn't allow packet fragmentation and for this reason there is a lenght limit because the packet has sent at one time,while TCP allows fragmentation and there is no length limit.is it right?                                           2)Where do I download RTP C# library?                                     3)I read document about RTP and it says that RTP has a various control for packets(sort,error...).My question is:why if its has the same controls of tcp it uses

Comment: UDP protocol?What is the reason?

Comment: @alessiovinaccia: UDP packets can be fragmented. The usual maximum size of an IP packet is 1500 bytes or so.

Comment: and but why for TCP there is no a lenght limit while for UDP is?

Comment: UDP is message-oriented, and a message must have some boundaries. In UDP, length of message is encoded with 16 bits, therefore the 64K limit. TCP transmits stream of data, so you can send any amount of data, but there are no any 'message boundaries' in the stream: you can sometimes send two bytes together, but receive them separately, one by one, or vice verca. At the lower level, TCP packets are quite limited in size, but an application works with stream of data and has no (well, shouldn't in general) any notion about size of underlying TCP packets.