# C# UDP protocol image sending

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

I simply try to send a screen shot using Udp protocol this is the code:

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram,
       ProtocolType.Udp);

        IPAddress broadcast = IPAddress.Parse("10.0.0.4");

        Bitmap bitmap=GetDesktopImage();//generate screenshot.
        byte[] sendbuf = imageToByteArray(bitmap);
        IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(broadcast, 10);

        s.SendTo(sendbuf, ep);

        Console.WriteLine("Message sent to the broadcast address");

    }
```

ImageToByteArray is a function which converts the image into a byte array you can see [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15460/C-Image-to-Byte-Array-and-Byte-Array-to-Image-Conv).

However im getting an odd exception when the `s.SendTo()` line is executed with the following error details:

> A message sent on a datagram socket was larger than the internal message buffer or some other network limit, or the buffer used to receive a datagram into was smaller than the datagram itself

Im not sure but i think it's related to the size of the data sent..
Any help?

Comment: The message sounds pretty clear to me; UDP is a much simpler protocol than TCP, and you're sending too much in a single packet... you'll need to cut the data into pieces (and reassemble, assuming the receiver gets them all)

Comment: @MarcGravell how will i be able to cut the byte array which contains the whole image? would i have to merge it in the other side?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UDP socket C#.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18563693/udp-socket-c-net)

Comment: Yes, break your array up into smaller pieces.  Try sending 1024 or 2048 bytes at a time (per packet) and reassemble them on the receiving side and see if it works that way.